# How to simulate partial success in `GCM` device group notifications

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

When I send notification to `Device Groups` I get the following response

```
{
  "success": 2,
  "failure": 0
}
```

I wanted to simulate partial success (https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/notifications#http_response) so that I can test my retry logic. A response like below-

```
{
  "success":1,
  "failure":2,
  "failed_registration_ids":[
     "regId1",
     "regId2"
  ]
}
```

How should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In order to have a "partial success" response, you need to have `not_registered_ids` and/or `invalid_registration_ids`. A "not registered id" is a registration id that was valid. According to [GCM documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes): "An existing registration token may cease to be valid in a number of scenarios...". You can try the following to have a partial successful push:

- Client app unregisters with GCM.
- Client app is automatically unregistered, which can happen if the user uninstalls the application.
- Client app is updated but the new version is not configured to receive messages.

A partial successful push may also have `to_be_retried_ids` so that the user can retry these specific registration ids as they failed because the server returned with `InternalServerError` or `Unavailable`.

Comment: Tried all the scenarios you mentioned to get `partial success`. But in all the cases their are no failures. Only the no of success decreases as if the registration id is removed from the group.

Comment: This might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30496492/what-is-a-good-way-to-return-a-partial-success-response-for-a-rest-api