# what http code to return for file upload

Tags: rest, http

I have a rest API to upload multiple files.
It returns an ID per file uploaded and a message, per file as well, which tells which error has occurred, if any.

Should I always return 200 with the json?

what if all files failed?
and what if some files only have failed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP status code for a partial successful request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8472935/http-status-code-for-a-partial-successful-request)

Comment: here is the quick lookout https://httpstatuses.com/  i think of 202 and 207 as to choose from as suggested by previous link

Comment: The other link was useful; I'll use a 207. Thanks!

Comment: This [link](https://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html) is also useful for people that see this question after long time like me