# how to handle errors and status codes with server side events

Tags: http, error-handling, http-status-codes, server-sent-events

I am wondering about how to handle errors when sending data via SSE

**Regular HTTP**

If for example I want to fetch a `User` record by `id` via an http endpoint `/users/:id` and I encounter a non existing user I would respond with status code `404` and the client would handle it.

**SSE**

Now I'm wondering how this would look like for SSE. Let's say my endpoint is `/users` and takes a list of ids `?user_ids=[1, 2, 3]`. The endpoint should find each record and send the results one by one. If the user with id `3` cannot be found, what is the protocol to convey this to the client?

Answer (score 0):

I found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8472935/http-status-code-for-a-partial-successful-request) on the subject:
**207** is a correct answer. The interesting fact is in the comments

> The nice thing about it is that you can return as much or little of pertinent data as you want

I use :
**200** with a partial content (mentionned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22911940/11825162)) as your data is partial yet pertinent

Do not use:
**202** does mean the request is being processed.